# is "common" module in Standard Library?

Tags: python, struct, module

I got this script for my program. The program uses python for scripting. Anyway, the script has this line

```
from common import Struct
```

Is this part of Python's standard library? because my python seems to be missing it. Maybe it is deprecated?
The script didn't include anything else but that one python file, so i guessed it's not a module made by the script creator.

Comment: as per my knowledge, there is "struct" module in standard python library but not common or "Struct". check functionality of "Struct" in your code, it could give you more idea for use of Struct.

as @eryksun said, common should be the python module in your python project and "Struct" could be the class or file.

Comment: It isn't part of the standard in python 2.5, 2.6 or 2.7. I suspect the author of the script must have put all common utilities in a module called `common` :-)

Answer (score 5):

I would suggest you check for a common.py file and add it to your PYTHONPATH.

if you are using some sort of unix/bsd you could try to do a "locate common.py" and check if it has a Struct somewhere.

Hope this helps

Comment: But multiple problems: 1) locate may not exist on the platform used or the underlying DB not being up to date (hence false positives/negatives), and 2) a Python `common` module may not necessarily be defined by a file `common.py`, you could as well have `common/__init__py`, `common/a.py`,  `common/b.py`, etc. so a search on `common.py` would yield nothing but be a false negative.

Answer (score 1):

In your script, just add after the line you quoted:

```
import sys
print sys.modules['common']
```

And it will show you the path where the module `common` was imported from.

Based on this you could easily see if it is a Python standard library or not.

Alternatively if you go to any page like https://docs.python.org/3/library/index.html you can see the list of modules included with Python.

In both cases I think you can come to the conclusion that there is no `common` module shipped with Python, and I would find it to be a very bad name if it existed like that.